# AWS S3 I can fetch the data but I can't assign the data to a value

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are trying to get the data from the aws s3 bucket and export it. The code below gets the data, prints it on the consoleLog(data.Body.toString()) but when initializing it to the text using parser it just does not do it, it is either printed undefined or empty or zero. We tried to replace single quotation marks with double, we tried initializing the value without using the parser etc. We tried everything but nothing changes, any kind of initialization will take the value and make it zero/empty and we can't understand why. What is the problem here?
index.js

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
var text = '';

// Our default route

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "AKIAZPS6KVMQRLPVK6EZ",
    secretAccessKey: "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",
    region: 'us-east-2'
    });
let s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
    Bucket: 'cs319-event',
    Key: 'IEEE_2.json'
}
s3.getObject(params, function(err,data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else{    
        console.log(data.Body.toString());
        text = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());
        
    }
});
console.log(text);
export {text};
```

output

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Event name 1",
    "club": "IEEE",
    "src": "images/kad n-akademisyen.jpg",
    "description": "enim corporis voluptatibus laudantium possimus alias dolorem voluptatem similique aut aliquam voluptatem voluptatem omnis id consequatur",
    "location": "Ankara",
    "date": "12.01.2022",
    "tags": [
        "X",
        "Y",
        "Z"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I assume its something with `data.Body.toString()`. Why are you all doing this? Shouldn't your JSON data already be a string?

Comment: Did you try to parse before logging? Maybe you've emptied the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`s3.getObject` is an asynchronous request.

This means, when you are exporting: `export {text};`, at this moment, `text` is equal to an empty string (`""`), and will always be an empty string for the modules that import this.

To make it work this way, you could export a function that retrieves the current value of `text` at invocation time, such as:

```js
// ... rest of index.js

function getText() {
  return text // Returns the current value of text at function call
}

export { getText }
```

However this isn't really very easy to work with. You could call `getText`, before AWS has returned any data. So depending when you call this, you could get an empty string, or you could get the data.

To make this simpler to work with, I would wrap this in a promise.

```js
// index.js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "XXX",
    secretAccessKey: "XXX",
    region: 'us-east-2'
    });

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
    Bucket: 'cs319-event',
    Key: 'IEEE_2.json'
}

function getText() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getObject(params, function(err,data){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        reject(err)
      }
      resolve(data.Body.toString()) 
    })
  })
}

export { getText };
```

And then usage in another module:

```js
// Example usage in another module

import { getText } from "./index";

getText()
  .then((data) => console.log("I got the data!", data))
  .catch((error) => {}) // error handle
```

This allows you to call and wait for the value to be returned from S3, and would be much more reliable than retrieving a variable that the value will change at an unknown time.